# How to change the color of a treemap in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I would like to know how to change the color for this treemap to "#453781FF". I have already tried with diferent ways, this is best posible solution, yet it is not the expected results, as you can see the color of this image is pink.

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

url_t = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frm1789/landslide-ea/master/df_treemap.csv"
df_t = read_csv(url_t)

ggplot2::ggplot(df_t, ggplot2::aes(area = n, label = country, fill = 
"#453781FF")) +
#geom_treemap(color = "red") +
geom_treemap(aes(alpha = v_alpha)) +
geom_treemap_text(fontface = "italic", colour = "white", place = 
"centre",
                grow = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is because you put the fill inside of `aes()`, so it's being interpreted as a factor variable. Put it outside and in the `geom_treemap()` - `geom_treemap(aes(alpha = v_alpha), color = "#453781FF")`.

Comment: Nope, doing that, the lines are in color "#453781FF" and the fill for each rectangle is now black. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Sorry, should have said `fill`, not `color`. The basic issue is still taking the color outside of `aes`.

Comment: I think the suggestion to do `geom_treemap(aes(alpha = v_alpha), fill = "#453781")` is correct. Note I also took off the `FF` from the colour code - that final part specifies the opacity, so it might interfere with the alpha aesthetic (I'm not actually sure).

Comment: @neilfws It works! Thank you so much! Thank you Marius for your help too.